# Java class for storing objects by index

Tags: java, arrays, list

Sorry, don't know how to explain it in brief in the title.
I need a java class that stores `<object number, object>` pairs generating incremental numbers automatically. If some item is deleted, the number it has shall be reused for the next stored item. Like that:

```
public class SerialStorage<T>
{
    Map<Integer, T> itemsStorage;
    Queue<Integer> deletedItemsStorage;
    int lastKnownMaxNumber;

    public SerialStorage()
    {
        itemsStorage = new HashMap<>();
        deletedItemsStorage = new ArrayDeque<>();
        lastKnownMaxNumber = 0;
    }

    /*
    Stores new item and returns it's number
     */
    public int putItem(T item)
    {
        int number;
        if (deletedItemsStorage.size() > 0)
        {
            number = deletedItemsStorage.remove();
        }
        else
        {
            number = ++lastKnownMaxNumber;
        }
        itemsStorage.put(number, item);
        return (number);
    }

    /*
    Get item by it's number
     */
    public T getItem(int number)
    {
        return (itemsStorage.get(number));
    }

    /*
    Removes item and returns it. Returns null if no such item found
     */
    public T removeItem(int number)
    {
        T removedItem = itemsStorage.get(number);
        if (removedItem != null)
        {
            deletedItemsStorage.add(number);
        }
        return (removedItem);
    }
}
```

Is there anything like this in the java standard libraries?

Comment: hashmap maybe?... but you are already using them, so idk what you mean by reusing the delete elements index

Comment: @Berto99 how could I find the first empty number in the HashMap?

Comment: "Is there anything like this in the java standard libraries?" No. What's the problem with the code you posted? Why can't you use it?

Comment: @Oleg Just don't want to reinvent the wheel. I know java libraries have almost anything, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @BbIKTOP Okay. You have a very specific requirement. I'm 99% sure the answer is no.

Comment: @Oleg Maybe, but it's always good to ask. I never met this as well, but I suppose I didn't use 90% of java standard classes.

Comment: ArrayList, perhaps?

Comment: @NomadMaker how?

Comment: It fits your first criterion (generates incremental numbers automatically). Your second criterion takes a bit of work (deleted numbers are reused). You could replace deleted values with null, and then reuse them as necessary.

Comment: @NomadMaker The question is: "is there a standard class that meets all criteria?" What are you answering to? And how these nulls would help? D oyou propose to iterate over map's keyset to find a first null? ))))

Comment: It fits the title perfectly: Java class for storing objects by index. That's what ArrayList does.

Comment: @NomadMaker where did you see "store objects by indexes"? It's clearly stated "stores <object number, object> pairs generating incremental numbers automatically" Ok, please reread it

Comment: The title of your question is: Java class for storing objects by index

Comment: Please read the question, not just title

Comment: if you need O(1) to find the index, your is the only solution, and as far as i know, there is no such data structure in any language, but why you don't want to use your solution?

Comment: and suppouse to have inserted [1,2,3,4], now you delete 2, so you have [1, _ ,3,4], than is i insert 5, i should have [1,5,3,4]... am i right?

Comment: I need a map with reusable keys. keys shall be integer. It shall work with large amount of data. I put a code sample to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you´re looking for an ArrayList ?
They auto-index and they clean up so if you remove an item from the middle all the following items will slide one index down.

A brief example:

```
ArrayList<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("this is a test"); // index 0
strings.add("this is number two"); // index 1
strings.add("this is number three"); // index 2

System.out.println(strings.get(1));    
strings.remove(1);
System.out.println(strings.get(1));
```

After this you´ll have "this is a test" at index 0 and "this is number three" at index 1.

Comment: No, all existing items shall keep their reference numbers upon deletion of other items, of course.

Comment: Then you might also, if the maximum amoint of items is known, work with an simple array.
You´ll have to write a function that looks for the next, free number if you want to reallocate the deleted item indices but in theory that´s a simple for-loop with null-checking.

Con, it´s not dynamic so if you allocate the array to a size of 64 then you won´t be able to ad a 65th item without resizing the array (or creating a bigger one and copying over the date) which can be blazing fast with small amounts of data but very inperformant with big abounts

Comment: It would be extremely slow and inefficient solution. You could read about HashMap here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Not in every case. The HashMap uses an Array under the hood so the HashMap cannot be faster than the array if correctly implemented. 
Iterating over it and checking for null might be slower but you might as well Extend array and add an "lastId" int to it or similar.

Comment: I'd dare to advise you to read this, especially it's 4th chapter (4.4 to be precise) http://www.inr.ac.ru/~info21/ADen/AD2012.pdf

Comment: @BbIKTOP can you give me the Java implementation note or code for this ?
As far as I know HashMaps start off using arrays until they hit a point where they switch to TreeMap

Comment: Actually: 

    Implementation notes.

     This map usually acts as a binned (bucketed) hash table, but
     when bins get too large, they are transformed into bins of
     TreeNodes, each structured similarly to those in
     java.util.TreeMap

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/f08705540498/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l257

Comment: For a HashMap? src.zip usually comes with java distribution, didn't check it, I use intellij idea that shows me sources automatically

Comment: See? No arrays here )))

Comment: No Arrays ? What´s the "table" variable in HashMap ?

Comment: ```$ grep Array HashMap.java
            SharedSecrets.getJavaOISAccess().checkArray(s, Map.Entry[].class, cap);
$```

Answer (score 0):

What you might need is a Map. But it won't generate the indexes automatically That is up to you.

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = New HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.add(findMissingPositive(map.KeySet(), map.KeySet().size()), "New String");
```

You might use a function that retrieves the smallest number that is missing from the keys.

```
static int findMissingPositive(int arr[], int size) 
    { 
        int i; 

        // Mark arr[i] as visited by making 
        // arr[arr[i] - 1] negative. Note that 
        // 1 is subtracted because index start 
        // from 0 and positive numbers start from 1 
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            int x = Math.abs(arr[i]); 
            if (x - 1 < size && arr[x - 1] > 0) 
                arr[x - 1] = -arr[x - 1]; 
        } 

        // Return the first index value at which 
        // is positive 
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
            if (arr[i] > 0) 
                return i + 1; // 1 is added becuase indexes 
        // start from 0 

        return size + 1; 
    }
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-positive-number-missing-from-an-unsorted-array/

Comment: I suppose iterating over a keyset of 5-6 million items for 200-300 million times is a quite bad idea

Comment: Well, you edited your answer. Finding the key is the main task, "Just generate it somehow" is not an answer

Comment: I have put an example of a function that does it for you. If you have that amount of data, i suggest you storing in a database. A primary key will solve this problem for you.

Comment: ok ty.
You know, it's a bit common here. Every time I ask a question, there are always people who didn't understand it, but explain me why shall I ask it the way they know an answer and people answering something else I didn't ask. I understand they're trying to help (maybe) that's why I spent a lot of time trying to formulate my question so it wouldn't be misunderstood, but no success. So, I am annoying mostly by myself that I was not able to prevent that misunderstanding.

Comment: Forgot to mention another category of answers: 'i do not know how to do that, but here, I know how to do something completely different" )))

Comment: I don't want to downvote but iterating over an array is a terrible idea. Never do that, there are lists, queues, maps etc invented to prevent that.